# When comparing two files, how do I skip (ignore) blank lines?

Tags: perl, file, blank-line

I'm comparing line against line of two text files, `ref.txt` (reference) and `log.txt`. But there may be an arbitrary number of blank lines in either file that I'd like to ignore; how can I accomplish this?

**ref.txt**

```
one

two


three



end
```

**log.txt**

```
one
two
three
end
```

There would be no incorrect log lines in the output, in other words `log.txt` matches with `ref.txt`.

What I like to accomplish in pseudo code:

```
while (traversing both files at same time) {
    if ($l is blank line || $r is blank line) {
        if ($l is blank line)
            skip to next non-blank line
        if ($r is blank line)
            skip to next non-blank line
    }
    #continue with line by line comparison...
}
```

My current code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $logPath    = ${ARGV [0]};
my $refLogPath = ${ARGV [1]} my $r;    #ref log line
my $l;                                 #log line

open INLOG, $logPath    or die $!;
open INREF, $refLogPath or die $!;

while (defined($l = <INLOG>) and defined($r = <INREF>)) {
    #code for skipping blank lines?
    if ($l ne $r) {
        print $l, "\n";                #Output incorrect line in log file
        $boolRef = 0;                  #false==0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are on a Linux platform, use :

```
diff -B ref.txt log.txt
```

The `-B` option causes changes that just insert or delete blank lines to be ignored

Answer (score 2):

You can skip blank lines by comparing it to this regular expression:

```
next if $line =~ /^\s*$/
```

This will match any white space or newline characters which can potentially make up a blank line.

Comment: It seems more understandable (to me, at least) to write that as `next unless $line =~ /\S/`.

Comment: @DaveCross I suppose that your version ensures that there is something on the line read. There is always more the one way to do it int Perl!

Comment: Yeah. I switched to my approach after dealing with one too many files where the "empty" lines actually contained spaces and/or tabs.

Answer (score 2):

This way seems the most "perl-like" to me. No fancy loops or anything, just slurp the files and grep out the blank lines.

```
use warnings;

$f1 = "path/file/1";
$f2 = "path/file/2";

open(IN1, "<$f1") or die "Cannot open file: $f1 ($!)\n";
open(IN2, "<$f2") or die "Cannot open file: $f2 ($!)\n";

chomp(@lines1 = <IN1>); # slurp the files
chomp(@lines2 = <IN2>);

@l1 = grep(!/^\s*$/,@lines1); # get the files without empty lines
@l2 = grep(!/^\s*$/,@lines2);

# something like this to print the non-matching lines
for $i (0 .. $#l1) {
   print "[$f1 $i]: $l1[$i]\n[$f2 $i]: $l2[$i]\n" if($l1[$i] ne $l2[$i]);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps rewrite those greps as `@l1 = grep(/\S/, @lines1)` etc.

Comment: How do I retrieve individual lines from the @l1 and @l2?

Comment: This isn't perfect, as one mismatched line will make all the ones below it be mismatches too. I thought I'd share this as an exploration of perl's file slurping/grepping ability. Definitely just use `diff -B` if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop to find each line, each time:

```
while(1) {
    while(defined($l = <INLOG>) and $l eq "") {}
    while(defined($r = <INREF>) and $r eq "") {}

    if(!defined($l) or !defined($r)) {
        break;
    }

    if($l ne $r) {
        print $l, "\n";
        $boolRef = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
man diff

diff -B ref.txt log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# line skipping code
while (defined($l=<INLOG>) && $l =~ /^$/ ) {}  # no-op loop exits with $l that has length

while (defined($r=<INREF>) && $r =~ /^$/ ) {}  # no-op loop exits with $r that has length
```